# Dynamic drop list show phrase before every item

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created this form it loads dynamic drop list with first option `select` but it is showing option `select` before every list item.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">
    <?php echo get_phrase( 'teacher');?>
  </label>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <select name="teacher_id" class="form-control select2" style="width:100%;">
      <?php $teachers=$ this->db->get('teacher')->result_array(); foreach($teachers as $row): ?>
      <option value="">
        <?php echo get_phrase( 'select');?>
      </option>
      <option value="<?php echo $row['teacher_id'];?>">
        <?php echo $row[ 'name'];?>
      </option>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Function get_phrase:

```
if ( ! function_exists('get_phrase')){

function get_phrase($phrase = '') {
    $CI =&  get_instance();
    $CI->load->database();
    $current_language   =   $CI->db->get_where('settings' , array('type' => 'language'))->row()->description;

    if ( $current_language  ==  '') {
        $current_language   =   'english';
        $CI->session->set_userdata('current_language' , $current_language);
    }


    /** insert blank phrases initially and populating the language db ***/
    $check_phrase   =   $CI->db->get_where('language' , array('phrase' => $phrase))->row()->phrase;
    if ( $check_phrase  !=      $phrase)
        $CI->db->insert('language' , array('phrase' => $phrase));


    // query for finding the phrase from `language` table
    $query  =   $CI->db->get_where('language' , array('phrase' => $phrase));
    $row    =   $query->row();  

    // return the current sessioned language field of according phrase, else return uppercase spaced word
    if (isset($row->$current_language) && $row->$current_language !="")
        return $row->$current_language;
    else 
        return ucwords(str_replace('_',' ',$phrase));
}
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what does `get_phrase` function do? Is it showing text only?

Comment: there is language file from where it get the value for Select like in this case it shows "select class"

Comment: please post your `get_phrase` function

Comment: check the orignal post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
   <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('teacher');?></label>
       <div class="col-sm-5">
           <select name="teacher_id" class="form-control select2" style="width:100%;">
               <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select');?></option>
               <?php 
               $teachers = $this->db->get('teacher')->result_array();
               foreach($teachers as $row):
               ?>
                   <option value="<?php echo $row['teacher_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
               <?php
               endforeach;
               ?>
           </select>
       </div>
   </div>
```